# Stored Procedure that only returns the value for one row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Somewhere I just need to pass in the `primary key` of a personnel and find him in database and return the value of one of the columns of that table for him to the caller - it is a `bit` column - . Pretty simple and I wrote it like this. I just wanted to see if there is a better way of writing the stored procedure to achieve the same goal or not.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GetPersonnelInfo]
    @PersonnelPK INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Personnel AS p WHERE p.PersonnelPK = @PersonnelPK)
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP (1) p.IsTeacher From Personnel p Where p.PersonnelPK = @PersonnelPK
    END;
END;
GO
```

Comment: why not just `SELECT ISNULL(p.IsTeacher, 0) ....`, you could save the top and exists

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way - remove the `if exists` - its completely useless. Also, you don't need the `top(1)`, since the primary key is unique by definition the stored procedure will only ever return one row, or nothing if the primary key value is not found.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GetPersonnelInfo]
    @PersonnelPK INT
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT IsTeacher 
    FROM dbo.Personnel 
    WHERE PersonnelPK = @PersonnelPK;
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

First, the `exists` seems superfluous, so:

```
SELECT TOP (1) p.IsTeacher From Personnel p Where p.PersonnelPK = @PersonnelPK;
```

If there is no matching row, this returns no rows.

Second, it is totally unclear to me why you would use a stored procedure like this.  You can create a user-defined scalar function which seems more useful.

Comment: oh I just hadn't used functions before. I might convert it to Function then. ... But then I also thought maybe in future I need to return more columns about this personnel so I could keep adding them to this one

Answer (score 1):

Yea, just

```
SELECT p.IsTeacher 
FROM Personnel p 
WHERE p.PersonnelSys = @PersonnelPK
```

Since it is the primary key there can only be one result at most, so no need for `TOP 1`. And the `IF EXISTS` is just unnecessary when you can return the result directly.